# iPhone OpenGL : Using gluUnProject (port) and detecting clicking on an object

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, matrix, glu

please help, this is my 4th question about this, I trying so hard I tried everything!

All I want to do is detect clicking on a object(cube) in a 3D World (3D world created).
This does it http://blog.nova-box.com/2010/05/iphone-ray-picking-glunproject-sample.html but has a completely different app structure and does a lot with render buffers etc.

I am trying to use using gluUnProject (someone has ported it).

On touch

```
    CGPoint pos = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];

 glGetIntegerv( GL_VIEWPORT, __viewport );
 glGetFloatv( GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, __modelview );
 glGetFloatv( GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, __projection ); 

 int i = 0;
 for (NSDictionary *item in self.players) {

  IMPoint3D playerPos;

  playerPos.x = [[item objectForKey:@"posX"] floatValue];
  playerPos.z = [[item objectForKey:@"posZ"] floatValue];
  playerPos.y = 1.0f;

  if([self checkCollission:pos object:playerPos])
  {
   NSLog(@"FIRE I LOVE YOU MAN %i", i);
  }

  i ++;
 }
```

Collision function taken from other project

```
    #define RAY_ITERATIONS 1000
     #define COLLISION_RADIUS 0.1f

-(Boolean) checkCollission:(CGPoint)winPos object:(IMPoint3D) _object { 

 winPos.y = (float)__viewport[3] - winPos.y;

 Point3D nearPoint;
 Point3D farPoint;
 Point3D rayVector;

 //Retreiving position projected on near plan
 gluUnProject( winPos.x, winPos.y , 0, __modelview, __projection, __viewport, &nearPoint.x, &nearPoint.y, &nearPoint.z);

 //Retreiving position projected on far plan
 gluUnProject( winPos.x, winPos.y,  1, __modelview, __projection, __viewport, &farPoint.x, &farPoint.y, &farPoint.z);

 //Processing ray vector
 rayVector.x = farPoint.x - nearPoint.x;
 rayVector.y = farPoint.y - nearPoint.y;
 rayVector.z = farPoint.z - nearPoint.z;

 float rayLength = sqrtf(POW2(rayVector.x) + POW2(rayVector.y) + POW2(rayVector.z));

 //normalizing ray vector
 rayVector.x /= rayLength;
 rayVector.y /= rayLength;
 rayVector.z /= rayLength;

 Point3D collisionPoint;
 Point3D objectCenter = {_object.x, _object.y, _object.z};

 //Iterating over ray vector to check collisions
 for(int i = 0; i < RAY_ITERATIONS; i++)
 {
  collisionPoint.x = rayVector.x * rayLength/RAY_ITERATIONS*i;
  collisionPoint.y = rayVector.y * rayLength/RAY_ITERATIONS*i;
  collisionPoint.z = rayVector.z * rayLength/RAY_ITERATIONS*i;

  //Checking collision 
  if([Tools poinSphereCollision:collisionPoint center:objectCenter radius:COLLISION_RADIUS])
  {
   return TRUE;
  }
 }

 return FALSE; 
}
```

If someone can work out the error, I will even paypal some cash over (if that's allowed), this has given me a headache for days.  I think its something to do when I get the projection and modelview matrix

Comment: what is the error?  Are you referring to logic error or syntax error?

Comment: @Joe, I honestly don't think its that. especially as I am now using a different function.  You have the source mate :)  @Stephen.  The error is that it does not pickup any objects that I click on.  I am willing to post the complete source if required.

Comment: You have the zip file dont you?

Comment: For future readers: on iOS there is now `GLKMathUnproject` function so there is no need to port other solutions. It is part of `GLKit Math Utilities`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant't be sure, but It seems that the coordinate system is wrong. I use (for 2D) something like this:

```
- (CGPoint) unProject: (CGPoint) point
{
    GLfloat x=0, y=0, z=0;
    GLfloat modelMatrix[16]; 
    GLfloat projMatrix[16];
    GLint viewport[4];
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelMatrix);
    glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projMatrix);
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);

    CGPoint result = { 0.0f/0.0f, 0.0f/0.0f };
    if(gluUnProject(point.x, size.height-point.y, 0, modelMatrix, projMatrix, viewport, &x, &y, &z) == GL_TRUE) { 
        result.x = x;
        result.y = y;
        //Since we're using an ortho projection, we can ignore z.
        UNUSED(z);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note this: `size.height-point.y` where size contains the `size` of the screen. You have to remember that the default coordinate system of the screen in Core Animation for iOS is different from the one used by OpenGL.

If you have a translation applied, it is very difficult to figure out what's going on.

I use this implementation of gluUnProject:
http://www.codng.com/2011/02/gluunproject-for-iphoneios.html
(disclaimer: it is my personal blog).

I know this doesn't fully answer your question, but it might help.

Answer (score 0):

I posting this as the complete source of the class, I sure its something to do with the project matrix not working

```
#import "GLViewController.h" 
#import "ConstantsAndMacros.h" 
#import "OpenGLCommon.h"
#import "WorldAppDelegate.h"
#import "Tools.h"
#import "glu.h"

#define SPEED_MOVE 0.025 
#define SPEED_TURN 0.05
#define MapSizeX 20
#define MapSizeZ 20

typedef struct 
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
} IMPoint3D;

@interface GLViewController ()

- (void)updateData;
- (BOOL)checkCollisionWithX:(float)x andWithZ:(float)z;
- (void)loadTextures:(NSString *)textureName andWithIndex:(int)index;
- (void)handleTouches;
- (void)updateCoords;
- (void)setupPlayer;
- (void)addScene;
- (void)loadTextureList;
- (void)loadController;
- (Boolean) checkCollission:(CGPoint)winPos object:(IMPoint3D) _object;
- (CGPoint)getScreenCoorOfPoint:(IMPoint3D)_point3D;
@end

@implementation GLViewController

@synthesize deviceID, players, label,collisionArray, baseURL;

-(void)setupView:(GLView*)view { 

    const GLfloat zNear = 0.1, zFar = 1000.0, fieldOfView = 120.0; 
    GLfloat size = zNear * tanf(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(fieldOfView) / 8.0);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); 
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

    //Rotate the view
    glRotatef(-90,0,0,1);

    CGRect rect = self.view.bounds; 
    glFrustumf(-size, size, -size / (rect.size.width / rect.size.height), size / (rect.size.width / rect.size.height), zNear, zFar);

    glViewport(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);

    // Starting position
    eye[0] = -0; 
    eye[1] = 3;
    eye[2] = -10; 
    center[0] = 0; 
    center[1] = 1.5;
    center[2] = 0;

    [self loadTextureList];
    [self loadController];
    [self loadTextureList ];
    [self addScene];    
    [self setupPlayer];
    [self updateCoords]; 

} 


// ...
- (void)drawView:(UIView *)theView { 

    // floor
    const GLfloat floorVertices[] = { 
        -1, 0.0f, 1,
        1, 0.0f, 1,
        1, 0.0f, -1, 
        -1, 0.0f, -1
        };

    const GLshort floorTextureCoords[] = {
        0, 1, // top left
        0, 0, // bottom left
        1, 0, //bottom right
        1, 1  //top right
    };

    // Colour cube
    static const GLubyte cubeNumberOfIndices = 36;

    const GLubyte colourCubeFaceColors[] = {
        0,255,0,255,
        255,125,0,255,
        255,0,0,255,
        255,255,0,255,
        0,0,255,255,
        255,0,255,255
    };


    static const Vertex3D texturedVertices[]= {
        {-1.0, 1.0, 1.0},             // vertices[0]
        {1.0, 1.0, 1.0},              // vertices[1]
        {-1.0, -1.0, 1.0},             // vertices[2]
        {-1.0, -1.0, 1.0},            // vertices[3]
        {1.0, 1.0, 1.0},             // vertices[4]
        {1.0, -1.0, 1.0},             // vertices[5]
        {-1.0, 1.0, 1.0},              // vertices[6]
        {-1.0, 1.0, -1.0},             // vertices[7]
        {-1.0, -1.0, 1.0},            // vertices[8]
        {-1.0, -1.0, 1.0},            // vertices[9]
        {-1.0, 1.0, -1.0},             // vertices[10]
        {-1.0, -1.0, -1.0},         // vertices[11]
        {-1.0, 1.0, -1.0},             // vertices[12]
        {1.0, 1.0, -1.0},              // vertices[13]
        {-1.0, -1.0, -1.0},             // vertices[14]
        {-1.0, -1.0, -1.0},            // vertices[15]
        {1.0, 1.0, -1.0},             // vertices[16]
        {1.0, -1.0, -1.0}, 
        {1.0, 1.0, 1.0},
        {1.0, 1.0, -1.0},
        {1.0, -1.0, 1.0},
        {1.0, -1.0, 1.0},
        {1.0, 1.0, -1.0},
        {1.0, -1.0, -1.0},
        {-1.0, 1.0, 1.0},
        {-1.0, 1.0, -1.0},
        {1.0, 1.0, 1.0},
        {1.0, 1.0, 1.0},
        {-1.0, 1.0, -1.0},
        {1.0, 1.0, -1.0},
        {-1.0, -1.0, 1.0},
        {-1.0, -1.0, -1.0},
        {1.0, -1.0, 1.0},
        {1.0, -1.0, 1.0},
        {-1.0, -1.0, -1.0},
        {1.0, -1.0, -1.0},
    };

    static const GLubyte texturedCube[] = {
        0, 1, 2,
        3, 4, 5,
        6, 7, 8,
        9, 10, 11,
        12, 13, 14,
        15, 16, 17,
        18, 19, 20,
        21, 22, 23,
        24, 25, 26, 
        27, 28, 29,
        30, 31, 32, 
        33, 34, 35,
    };

    static const GLfloat texturedCubeCoord[] = {
        0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0,

        1.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0,

        1.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0,

        0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0,

        0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0,

        0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0,
        0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 0.0,

    };


    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);


    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    [self handleTouches];

    //view : prebaked in to OPenGL Template
    gluLookAt(eye[0], eye[1], eye[2],center[0],  center[1], center[2], 0.0, 1, 0.0);

    // draw the floor
    glPushMatrix();

    //tell GL about our texture 
    glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
    glScalef(20,20,1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glScalef(20,1,20);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_SHORT, 0, floorTextureCoords);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, floorVertices); 
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);

    glPopMatrix();

    for (NSString *coords in self.collisionArray) {

        NSArray *coordsArray = [coords componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

        float x =  [[coordsArray objectAtIndex:0] floatValue] ;
        float z =  [[coordsArray objectAtIndex:1] floatValue] ;
        float width =  ([[coordsArray objectAtIndex:2] floatValue] /2) ;
        float length =   ([[coordsArray objectAtIndex:3] floatValue] /2) ;

        glPushMatrix();

        //tell GL about our texture
        glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
        glLoadIdentity();

        if (width > length) {
            glScalef(width, 3, length);
        } else {
            glScalef(length, 3, width);
        }

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ([[coordsArray objectAtIndex:4] floatValue]));
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glTranslatef(x, 3, z);
        glScalef(width, 3, length);
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, texturedVertices);
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texturedCubeCoord);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,cubeNumberOfIndices , GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texturedCube);

        glPopMatrix();
    }

    float x;
    float z;
    float playerRotation;

    for (NSDictionary *item in self.players) {

        x = [[item objectForKey:@"posX"] floatValue];
        z = [[item objectForKey:@"posZ"] floatValue];
        playerRotation = [[item objectForKey:@"rotation"] floatValue];

        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(x, 1 , z);
        glRotatef(playerRotation, 0, 1, 0);


        //Reset textures
        glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
        glLoadIdentity();

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, texturedVertices);
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texturedCubeCoord);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &texturedCube[0]);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 4);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &texturedCube[6]);

        int colorIndex = 0;
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        glColor4ub(colourCubeFaceColors[colorIndex], colourCubeFaceColors[colorIndex+1], colourCubeFaceColors[colorIndex+2], colourCubeFaceColors[colorIndex+3]);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &texturedCube[12]);

        glPopMatrix();
    }

    // GL teardown
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint pos = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];

    int i = 0;
    for (NSDictionary *item in self.players) {

        IMPoint3D playerPos;

        playerPos.x = [[item objectForKey:@"posX"] floatValue];
        playerPos.z = [[item objectForKey:@"posZ"] floatValue];
        playerPos.y = 1.0f;

        if([self checkCollission:pos object:playerPos])
        {
            NSLog(@"FIRE I LOVE YOU MAN %i", i);
        }

    }


    //left
    if ( pos.x >= 35 && pos.x <= 80 && pos.y >= 0 && pos.y <= 40) {
        action = ActionTurnLeft;

    //right 
    } else if ( pos.x >= 35 && pos.x <= 80 && pos.y >= 80 && pos.y <= 120) {
        action = ActionTurnRight;

    //forward
    } else if ( pos.x >= 80 && pos.x <= 120 && pos.y >= 32 && pos.y <= 82) {
        action = ActionMoveForward;

    //back
    } else if ( pos.x >= 0 && pos.x <= 40 && pos.y >= 32 && pos.y <= 82) {
        action = ActionMoveBackward;
    }

} 

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    action = ActionNone; 
}

#define RAY_ITERATIONS 1000
#define COLLISION_RADIUS 0.1f

-(Boolean) checkCollission:(CGPoint)winPos object:(IMPoint3D) _object { 

    glGetFloatv( GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, __projection );  
    glGetFloatv( GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, __modelview );
    glGetIntegerv( GL_VIEWPORT, __viewport );

    winPos.y = (float)__viewport[3] - winPos.y;

    Point3D nearPoint;
    Point3D farPoint;
    Point3D rayVector;

    //Retreiving position projected on near plan
    gluUnProject( winPos.x, winPos.y , 0, __modelview, __projection, __viewport, &nearPoint.x, &nearPoint.y, &nearPoint.z);

    //Retreiving position projected on far plan
    gluUnProject( winPos.x, winPos.y,  1, __modelview, __projection, __viewport, &farPoint.x, &farPoint.y, &farPoint.z);

    //Processing ray vector
    rayVector.x = farPoint.x - nearPoint.x;
    rayVector.y = farPoint.y - nearPoint.y;
    rayVector.z = farPoint.z - nearPoint.z;

    float rayLength = sqrtf(POW2(rayVector.x) + POW2(rayVector.y) + POW2(rayVector.z));

    //normalizing ray vector
    rayVector.x /= rayLength;
    rayVector.y /= rayLength;
    rayVector.z /= rayLength;

    Point3D collisionPoint;
    Point3D objectCenter = {_object.x, _object.y, _object.z};

    //Iterating over ray vector to check collisions
    for(int i = 0; i < RAY_ITERATIONS; i++)
    {
        collisionPoint.x = rayVector.x * rayLength/RAY_ITERATIONS*i;
        collisionPoint.y = rayVector.y * rayLength/RAY_ITERATIONS*i;
        collisionPoint.z = rayVector.z * rayLength/RAY_ITERATIONS*i;

        //Checking collision 
        if([Tools poinSphereCollision:collisionPoint center:objectCenter radius:COLLISION_RADIUS])
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    return FALSE;   
} 

/* does not work
-(CGPoint)getScreenCoorOfPoint:(IMPoint3D)_point3D
{
    GLfloat     p[16];   // Where The 16 Doubles Of The Projection Matrix Are To Be Stored
    glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, p);                           // Retrieve The Projection Matrix
    /*
     Multiply M * point
     */
    //GLfloat _p[] = {p[0]*_point3D.x +p[4]*_point3D.y +p[8]*_point3D.z + p[12],
    //  p[1]*_point3D.x +p[5]*_point3D.y +p[9]*_point3D.z + p[13],
    //  p[2]*_point3D.x +p[6]*_point3D.y +p[10]*_point3D.z+ p[14],
    //  p[3]*_point3D.x +p[7]*_point3D.y +p[11]*_point3D.z+ p[15]};
    /*
     divide by scale factor
     */
   // CGPoint _p2D = {_p[0]/_p[3], _p[1]/_p[3]};
    /*
     get result in screen coordinates. In this case I'm in landscape mode
     */
    //return (CGPoint) {_p2D.x*240.0f + 240.0f, (1.0f - _p2D.y) *160.0f};
}
*/

- (void)handleTouches { 
    if (action != ActionNone) {
        GLfloat v[] = {center[0] - eye[0], center[1] - eye[1], center[2] - eye[2]}; 

        switch (action) {
            case ActionMoveForward: 

                eye[0] += v[0] * SPEED_MOVE;
                eye[2] += v[2] * SPEED_MOVE;
                center[0] += v[0] * SPEED_MOVE;
                center[2] += v[2] * SPEED_MOVE;

                if ((eye[2] > MapSizeZ || eye[0] > MapSizeX  || eye[2] < -MapSizeZ || eye[0] < -MapSizeX)  || [self checkCollisionWithX:eye[0] andWithZ:eye[2]]){

                    eye[0] -= v[0] * SPEED_MOVE; 
                    eye[2] -= v[2] * SPEED_MOVE;
                    center[0] -= v[0] * SPEED_MOVE;
                    center[2] -= v[2] * SPEED_MOVE;
                }

                break;
            case ActionMoveBackward: 

                eye[0] -= v[0] * SPEED_MOVE; 
                eye[2] -= v[2] * SPEED_MOVE;
                center[0] -= v[0] * SPEED_MOVE;
                center[2] -= v[2] * SPEED_MOVE;

                if ((eye[2] > MapSizeZ || eye[0] > MapSizeX  || eye[2] < -MapSizeZ || eye[0] < -MapSizeX) || [self checkCollisionWithX:eye[0] andWithZ:eye[2]] ){

                    eye[0] += v[0] * SPEED_MOVE;
                    eye[2] += v[2] * SPEED_MOVE;
                    center[0] += v[0] * SPEED_MOVE;
                    center[2] += v[2] * SPEED_MOVE;
                }
                break;

            case ActionTurnLeft: 
                center[0] = eye[0] + cos(-SPEED_TURN)*v[0] - sin(-SPEED_TURN)*v[2]; 
                center[2] = eye[2] + sin(-SPEED_TURN)*v[0] + cos(-SPEED_TURN)*v[2]; 
                rotation -=2.865;
                break;

            case ActionTurnRight: 
                center[0] = eye[0] + cos(SPEED_TURN)*v[0] - sin(SPEED_TURN)*v[2];
                center[2] = eye[2] + sin(SPEED_TURN)*v[0] + cos(SPEED_TURN)*v[2]; 
                rotation +=2.865;
                break;
        }

    }

}

- (void)loadTextures:(NSString *)textureName andWithIndex:(int)index { 

    // load image as a CG ref 
    CGImageRef textureImage = [UIImage imageNamed:textureName].CGImage;
    // if failed, bail
    if (!textureImage) { 
        NSLog(@"Error: failed to load texture"); 
        return;
    }


    // figure out the width and height
    int texWidth = CGImageGetWidth(textureImage); 
    int texHeight = CGImageGetHeight(textureImage);

    // alloc space for the texture
    GLubyte *textureData = (GLubyte *)malloc(texWidth * texHeight * 4);

    // create a CA context ref
    CGContextRef textureContext = CGBitmapContextCreate( 
                                                        textureData, texWidth, texHeight, 8, texWidth * 4, 
                                                        CGImageGetColorSpace(textureImage),
                                                        kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast
                                                        );

    // draw the image to in-memory buffer
    CGContextDrawImage(textureContext, CGRectMake(0,0,texWidth,texHeight), textureImage);

    // done with context - release it
    CGContextRelease(textureContext); 

    // have GL create handle for our texture
    glGenTextures(1, &textures[index]); 

    // tell GL that the image is 2D
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[index]);

    // send our data down to GL, copy into graphics hardware
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texWidth, texHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData);

    // free our in-memory copy of the data
    free(textureData);

    // specify min/max filters
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    // tell GL to turn on textures
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); 

}

- (void)updateCoords {

    self.players = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@UpdatePlayer.aspx?playerIndex=%@&posX=%f&posZ=%f&rotation=%f", baseURL, self.deviceID, eye[0], eye[2], rotation]]];

    [self updateData]; 
}

- (void)updateData {

    NSInvocationOperation *op = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(updateCoords) object:nil];
    [[(WorldAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] sharedOperationQueue] addOperation:op];
    [op release];
}   

- (void)setupPlayer {

    // Device id
    UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    self.deviceID = [device uniqueIdentifier];

    NSDictionary *tempDict = [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@GetPlayerPosition.aspx?playerIndex=%@", baseURL, self.deviceID]]] autorelease];
    eye[0] = [[tempDict objectForKey:@"posX"] floatValue];
    eye[2] = [[tempDict objectForKey:@"posZ"] floatValue]  ;
    rotation = [[tempDict objectForKey:@"rotation"] floatValue];
}

- (void)addScene {


    self.collisionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self.collisionArray addObject:@"5,-4,4,4,1"];
    [self.collisionArray addObject:@"5, 4,4,4,1"];

    [self.collisionArray addObject:@"20,0,1,40,4"];
    [self.collisionArray addObject:@"-20,0,1,40,4"];

    [self.collisionArray addObject:@"0,-20,40,1,4"];
    [self.collisionArray addObject:@"0,20,40,1,4"];


}

- (void)loadTextureList {

    [self loadTextures:@"crate.png" andWithIndex:0];
    [self loadTextures:@"brick.jpg" andWithIndex:1];
    [self loadTextures:@"GrassTexture.png" andWithIndex:2];
    [self loadTextures:@"swtexnew.png" andWithIndex:3];

}

- (void)loadController {

    self.baseURL = @"http://burf2000.dyndns.org:90/Cubes/";

    //Controler
    UIImageView *joypadView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"StoneCompass.png"]];
    joypadView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 120);
    [self.view addSubview:joypadView];
    [joypadView release];

}

- (BOOL)checkCollisionWithX:(float)x andWithZ:(float)z {

    for (NSString *coords in self.collisionArray) {

        NSArray *coordsArray = [coords componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

        float x1 =  [[coordsArray objectAtIndex:0] floatValue] -   ([[coordsArray objectAtIndex:2] floatValue] /2) ;
        float z1 =  [[coordsArray objectAtIndex:1] floatValue] -   ([[coordsArray objectAtIndex:3] floatValue] /2) ;
        float x2 =  [[coordsArray objectAtIndex:0] floatValue] +   ([[coordsArray objectAtIndex:2] floatValue] /2) ;
        float z2 =  [[coordsArray objectAtIndex:1] floatValue] +   ([[coordsArray objectAtIndex:3] floatValue] /2) ;


        if ( x > x1 && x < x2  && z > z1  && z < z2 ) {

            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [deviceID release];
    [players release];
    [collisionArray release];
    [label release];
    [baseURL release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```